# AngularFire add in reverse order

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I need to add objects to Firebase in reverse order. Or reverse data when goes data binding. Or sort objects by time of create.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://[url].firebaseio.com/");
$scope.messages = $firebase(ref);

$scope.addMessage = function(e) {
    $scope.messages.$add({title: $scope.title, body: $scope.msg, time: $scope.getDate() });
}

<div class="well span3 pull-left note" ng-repeat="(key, msg) in messages">

    <button type='button' class='close' ng-click="messages.$remove(key)">×</button>
    <b>{{msg.time| date: 'medium'}}</b>
    <span>{{msg.title}}</span>
    <span>{{msg.body}}</span>
    <button ng-click="changeMessage(key)" class="btn btn-mini pull-right"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></button>      
</div>
```

I try to use OrderBy atribute for ng-repeat but this is not easy because in messages are stored objects.

Answer (score 13):

Check out the [chat example in angularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/partials/chat.html). It uses a [custom reverse filter](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/js/filters.js)

The reverse filter looks like so:

```
app.filter('reverse', function() {
      function toArray(list) {
         var k, out = [];
         if( list ) {
            if( angular.isArray(list) ) {
               out = list;
            }
            else if( typeof(list) === 'object' ) {
               for (k in list) {
                  if (list.hasOwnProperty(k)) { out.push(list[k]); }
               }
            }
         }
         return out;
      }
      return function(items) {
         return toArray(items).slice().reverse();
      };
   });
```

And the usage is like so:

```
<ul id="messages" ng-show="messages">
    <li ng-repeat="message in messages | reverse">{{message.text}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `orderByPriority` link is broken; it just goes to the root of the AngularFire documentation. The AngularFire API reference also doesn't contain "orderByPriority" anywhere. Additionally, the chat example no longer uses `orderByPriority` in the HTML. I'm guessing this answer is entirely obsolete?

Comment: Aha, so it looks to me like the relevant documentation now is at https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebase-constructor which notes *You may apply queries and limits to sync a subset of your data.* and provides a code example. I guess the AngularFire API for doing this has changed since this answer was written, since it doesn't seem to match up with what's in this answer?